# How to customize a Facebook Send Button?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to customize the appearance of a facebook 'Send' button.

I generate the button using the code provided in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/), however I don't have a clue of how I could modify the button's image or text ?

Could anyone give me an example? I guess javascript is my only option here?

My code looks like this right now:

```
<fb:send href="http://www.mywebsite.com/something"></fb:send>
```

This generates a button that looks like this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This article may help http://www.business.com/b2bmarketing/create-share-buttons/

Comment: You could also something to the affect of `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to share>&t=<title of content><img src="your_image.xxx"></a>`

Comment: This is not a share button, that's my point... can't believe there's no possible way to customize this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot customise the `<fb:send />` button. However, you can achieve the same functionality using `FB.ui` (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/). Use the `send` method, eg.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'send',
    name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
    link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html',
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can always create your own link and style it however you wish, then add the link from [this list of all social sharing button links list](http://atlchris.com/1665/how-to-create-custom-share-buttons-for-all-the-popular-social-services/) - this works for sharing to all sorts of social sites.

For Facebook's share link, replace `[URL]` and `[TITLE]` with your data using `urlencode()`in the following code in your link's href:

```
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=[URL]&title=[TITLE]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much SOL when it comes to customizing these Facebook buttons.  They have intentionally designed their buttons so that you can't change or customize them beyond the limited scope provided by Facebook.

Comment: Is there a way I could overcome this ? Maybe using Send Dialog ?

Comment: It is simply that they are in iframes which are inaccessible by scripts on your page. If you use a browser extension you can modify their look...or use the FB.ui

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's send button is in an `iframe`. If you wait for the `iframe` to load, you can select its contents with `$('iframe').contents()`. So replacing the text would look like

```
$(function(){
    $('.fb_iframe_widget iframe').on('load', function(){
        $(this).contents().find('.pluginButtonLabel').text('Custom Text');
    });
});
```